# Odd text positioning

Tags: css

I can't understand why the text in the paragraph within #intro is positioning itself in such a way: http://www.physoc.org.uk/  (the 'Hello everyone....' text near the top of the page).

I only have styling on #intro:

```
#intro {
    position:relative;
    top:160px;
    height:87px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-radius: 10px;
    moz-border-radius: 10px;
    webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

, Thank you

Comment: Have you seen that http://www.physoc.org.uk/wp-content/themes/physoc/js/jquery-1.3.2.js and http://www.physoc.org.uk/wp-content/themes/physoc/js/jquery.capSlide.js both of the links are dead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#intro p {
    margin: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -140px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

#### Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Problem sorted - I used another div within intro and then a h2 tag for the text (this stops the problem of the hello separating from the rest of the text for some reason) and then relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this:

```
#intro{ position: absolute; width: inherit; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the p tag absolute positioning:

```
   #intro{
       position:absolute;
   }
```